# Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to update to Spring Boot 2.7.0-SNAPSHOT.
WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated in this version.

Old WebSecurityConfig with WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (working fine):

```java
/**
 * SecurityConfig
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2UserServiceImpl oAuth2UserServiceImpl;

    /**
     * for development
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        // for development
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        // ignoring
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/lib/**", "/favicon.ico", "/oauth2");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login", "/error", "/message/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint("/login"));
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // OAuth2
        http.oauth2Login().loginPage("/").defaultSuccessUrl("/home", false);
        http.oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().userService(oAuth2UserServiceImpl);
        http.oauth2Login().successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.oauth2Login().failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);


        http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        http.csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .enableSessionUrlRewriting(false);
    }

    private MyAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        MyAuthenticationFilter filter = new MyAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler);

        filter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/authentication", "POST"));
        return filter;
    }

    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
        return new MyLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(loginFormUrl);
    }

}
```

After reading [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter), I have modified the new WebSecurityConfig:

```java
/**
 * SecurityConfig
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler customAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2UserServiceImpl oAuth2UserServiceImpl;

    /**
     * for development
     * 
     * @return
     */
    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        // for development
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().antMatchers(
                "/css/**", "/js/**", "/img/**", "/lib/**", "/favicon.ico", "/oauth2");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login", "/error", "/message/**").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin();
        http.exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint("/login"));
        http.addFilterBefore(authenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        // OAuth2
        http.oauth2Login().loginPage("/").defaultSuccessUrl("/home", false);
        http.oauth2Login().userInfoEndpoint().userService(oAuth2UserServiceImpl);
        http.oauth2Login().successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        http.oauth2Login().failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

        http.logout().logoutUrl("/logout").logoutSuccessUrl("/login").deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");

        http.csrf().disable();

        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.IF_REQUIRED)
                .enableSessionUrlRewriting(false);

        return http.build();
    }

    private MyAuthenticationFilter authenticationFilter() throws Exception {
        MyAuthenticationFilter filter = new MyAuthenticationFilter();

        // How can I fix this? ------------------------------------------
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        // --------------------------------------------------------------

        filter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler);
        filter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler);
        filter.setRequiresAuthenticationRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/authentication", "POST"));
        return filter;
    }

    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint(String loginFormUrl) {
        return new MyLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(loginFormUrl);
    }

}
```

I was able to fix two methods.
(#configure(WebSecurity web) and #configure(HttpSecurity http))

However, I can't figure out how to fix authenticationManagerBean().
Where do I get the AuthenticationManager from?

Answer (score 9):

Here's the entire class that took me day to configure. Hope it could save your time.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationSecurityConfig {

    private final UserDetailsService userService;
    private final AuthenticationConfiguration configuration;
    
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter filter = new CustomizedAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager());
        filter.setFilterProcessesUrl("/api/login");
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/login").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.addFilter(filter);
        
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
    
    @Autowired
    void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder builder) throws Exception {
        builder.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me when trying to rewrite my existing security config to remove deprecated class - 'WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter' for Spring Boot 2.7.2.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a [custom DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#jc-custom-dsls). This is actually how Spring Security works internally.

```java
public class MyCustomDsl extends AbstractHttpConfigurer<MyCustomDsl, HttpSecurity> {
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManager authenticationManager = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManager.class);
        http.addFilterBefore(new MyAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    public static MyCustomDsl customDsl() {
        return new MyCustomDsl();
    }
}
```

Then you can apply the custom DSL when building the `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // ...
    http.apply(customDsl());
    return http.build();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried. Indeed, the configure() method of the MyCustomDsl class is called after the filterChain() method of the SecurityConfig class.
However, MyAuthenticationFilter is not enabled at login. is it not a problem that http.addFIlterBefore() is called after http.build()?

Comment: @fsk5304 Can you explain in more detail what you mean by MyAuthenticationFilter is not enabled at login?

Comment: MyAuthenticationFilter is not executed during login authentication. For example, placing a breakpoint in MyAuthenticationFilter will not stop it, and writing System.out.println() in MyAuthenticationFilter will not output a string.

Comment: I Had the same problem with the Authentication Filter. In My case, removing http.httpBasic(withDefaults()); worked

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inject AuthenticationManager into other spring components, you can use the following configuration.

```
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
     return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
}
```

This approach has solved the problem for me and you can inject AuthenticationManager wherever you need.

EDIT:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration  {
    private final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception 
    {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried to do that, but couldn't figure out how to fix the `filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());` part. How should I fix my source code? Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't figure it out, so I fixed it anyway like this. `filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager(null));`
Then it worked for some reason. Is this ok? I think something is wrong.

Comment: @fsk5304 Maybe if you'll make the injection like this, it will solve the issue for you
`
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration  {
    private final AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
`
The AuthenticationConfiguration is injected via constructor in the example (you can inject it in which way you prefer)

Comment: Please check under EDIT in the main comment to see the indented code.