# Spring Security without WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter because of deprecating

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

This code doesn't work in last versions of Spring boot.  The error warning says that:

`WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`  is deprecated. So, how to do it?

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**/favicon.ico", "/css/**", "js/**", "/images/**", "/webjars/**")
                .permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
        http.formLogin();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Security without the WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71348952/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Of course I read them. I just tried to find an answer for me compering two functions in my project. So I just accidently copied/pasted wrong code from my project

Answer (score 0):

According to official documentation.

Spring Security 6 has removed `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` class. So you cant use

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {}
```

Instead you need to create `SecurityFilterChain` Bean.

For more information check this one
[resource](https://spring.io/blog/2022/02/21/spring-security-without-the-websecurityconfigureradapter)

Answer (score 0):

You have to expose a bean of SecurityFilterChain. You can write it in this way:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> 
            authorize.requestMatchers("/css/**", "js/**", "/images/**", "/webjars/**", "**.html").permitAll());
        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```